# Visualize data count in d3

Tags: d3.js

I want to visualize data count in d3. I have a dataset similar to this:

`[
   {
     "name": "Team blue",
     "color": "#0433ff"
     "count": 9
   },
   {
     "name": "Team red",
     "color": "#ff2600"
     "count": 12
   }
]`

and I want to visualize it like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/111iL.png

I understand the basics of data and enter() but I do not know which is the best way to create the red or blue boxes based on the count value.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us the code you have so far?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff this is a prototype: http://jsfiddle.net/LwmMW/ nothing fancy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`d3.range(number)`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_range) to generate a range of numbers from 1 to `number`. You can then combine this with [nested selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/). The code looks like this:

```
block.selectAll("span")
  .data(function(d) { return d3.range(d.count); })
  .enter()
  .append('span')
```

Complete demo (with fixed CSS) [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LwmMW/1/). The way of getting the color for the `span` elements is a bit hacky at the moment as it indexes into the top-level data set. A cleaner way would be to make this data part of the elements generated with `d3.range()` and is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I did your exercise :) does it look good for you? Any clue for improving it? http://jsfiddle.net/LwmMW/2/ Thank you again.